# Categorise data from database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, sorting, oledb

I've asked a non-full question before and was provided with an answer. However, I need some help with finishing it.

I have a piece of data coming from database in one column. This data comes in form as this:

```
    F-T
    F-T-O
    F-T-O-1
    F-T-O-12
    F-T-O-13
    A-L-7
    A-L-73
    A-L-74
    A-L-741
      .
      .
      .
```

I need to group this data in a dropdown (accordion) matter where the main accordion would contain "F-T" and "A-L-7". Clicking on "F-T" would then display inner data. If that data contains children it would be possible to go down the branches to the last child. Groups are made in tree type. Adding another letter will fall under the one with less letters : "F-T" contains "F-T-O"; "F-T-O" could contain "F-T-O-1" and so on. However, "F-T" would not contain "A-T-L".

The code I have received from the previous question has helped me to sort everything in a way I want it. The only thing missing now is to group the values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication50
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Category", typeof(string));

            string[] data = { (data from above as strings) };

        foreach (string d in data)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { d });
        }

        dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => new 
SortRecord(x,"Category")).CopyToDataTable();

    }
}
public class SortRecord : IComparer<SortRecord >, IComparable<SortRecord>
{
    string[] rowSplitArray;
    int length = 0;
    public SortRecord(DataRow x, string name)
    {
        rowSplitArray = x.Field<string>(name).Split(new char[] { '-' });
        length = rowSplitArray.Length;
    }

    public int Compare(SortRecord  rowA, SortRecord rowB)
    {
        int len = Math.Min(rowA.length, rowB.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
         if (rowA.rowSplitArray[i] != rowB.rowSplitArray[i])
         return 
         rowA.rowSplitArray[i].CompareTo(rowB.rowSplitArray[i]);
        }
          return rowA.length.CompareTo(rowB.length);
       }
        public int CompareTo(SortRecord row)
        {
            return Compare(this, row);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me out with this. Spend a lot of time, but can't seem to find a way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the rule to distinguish "root" from "subtree" is unclear, because a) the test data in the sample does not match the samples you gave above; and b) how would we know that "A-L-7" is to be regarded as a root? just because "A-L" is not part of the list?

Comment: Thanks for reply @dlatikay. I have just edited the question. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Try reasoning about it - what are the characteristics that separate a top category from its subcategories? How can a top category be identified among other top categories?